# how to show current date and time power bi reports

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have creating power bi reports using my excel data.one of my reports page want show current time and date .i have tired  power bi desktop after created new column i am include following query

```
 Get Date = NOW()
```

now added this columns some visuals showing correct time like

```
   11.09 Am
```

after reports published reports i am checking time showing same time

```
11.09Am
```

please any idea how to get current time after published reports? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you only have to refresh the report to see current time.

Answer (score 0):

Just refresh the report by clicking refresh button on top bar. If the problem still exists, describe it with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

use `TODAY()` method to find the current data

```
Subheading = "for events that occured up to "& FORMAT(TODAY(),"DD") & "th  " & FORMAT(TODAY(),"MMMM") & "
```

[image]